# Invoke git without loading user gitconfig

Tags: git

A git-interfaced tool written in Python breaks because of some settings in my local `~/.gitconfig`, namely `diff.noprefix=True`.

I know that I can use something like `git -c diff.noprefix=False diff` in the call but I fear other things will break in other parts of the tool or on other setups. I have been looking for a `--norc` or `-c /dev/null` parameter but didn't find my way in the documentation.

Comment: Sigh. This is why programs built on Git should always use its “plumbing” interface (e.g. `git diff-files`, `git diff-index`, and `git diff-tree`) and not the “porcelain” interface (e.g. `git diff`). The plumbing commands disregard user-preference items like `diff.noprefix`, so the output formats are stable (across Git versions and also users).

Answer (score 4):

Export a different value for `HOME` than your normal home directory. Git won't be able to find a ~/.gitconfig there (or can find a new one you define, which is missing the offensive parameter). Looks like you can also set a GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM export to decline usage of `/etc/git.config`, too.

Further details in [this gmane thread.](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/179235/focus=179241)